# Reading from JSON File C#

Tags: c#, json

Hey guys I have this json file (excerpt):
https://hastebin.com/uzifiteqol.json
I have created a discord bot which responds to commands and one of the commands is *card (card name)
This JSON file provides the stats of all the cards, but I want the user to access the lvl 9 stats based on the idname (card name he puts)
For example:
*card arrows
This should give the user the area damage of lvl 9 arrows that are shown in the json, but I am not sure how to access this stat. Heres what I have so far:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("/Users/me/Desktop/cardstatsfile.json");
```

This is where the json file location is on my computer (mac)
I am not sure how to go from there, I was thinking that I would need JToken.parse and parse through the file to look for the "idname" or the card specified by the user. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Clarification: Because there are 75 cards, I want to obtain the values of elixircost, rarity, ect and also all the lvl 9 stats just by providing the idname. Or do I need to reformat the JSON to do this?

Comment: It looks like you should probably write a model class, and deserialize the JSON as a list of that type. There are *lots* of examples of this on the web and in Json.NET tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

Deserialize to a POCO as below and then do the operations

```
public class Stat
{
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int areaDamage { get; set; }
    public int crownTowerDamage { get; set; }
    public int? hitpoints { get; set; }
    public int? dps { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string idName { get; set; }
    public string rarity { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int arena { get; set; }
    public int elixirCost { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public int radius { get; set; }
    public string target { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
    public string statsDate { get; set; }
    public int? hitSpeed { get; set; }
    public int? speed { get; set; }
    public int? deployTime { get; set; }
    public double? range { get; set; }
    public int? count { get; set; }
    public string transport { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write some POCO class to store that data after deserialization in object form. Use Newtonsoft for the deserialization task. `JsonConvert` class is your friend.